# Trying to stop TutorLMS from stripping backslashes from course content

Tags: wordpress, mathjax, sanitization, lms

I'm working on a TutorLMS project for a scientific institute. We're using MathJax-LaTeX to display math formulas in the course content.

To enter math symbols, MathJax-LaTeX uses backslashes for encoding, for example: \frac, \sum, \lambda etc.

However, TutorLMS strips the backslashes on save. In regular WP content, this doen't happen. TutorLMS support isn't helping.

Adding double backslashes works on the first save, because only the first backslash gets stripped. The next save, both are gone.

I'm looking to hook into the function that sanitizes the course content, but don't know where to look.

Comment: maybe look into this - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-embed-video-cause-by-sanitize_text_field/ if you go to tutor/includes/tutor-general-functions.php you will see that data is sanitized based on the input type. The function allows overwriting so you should be able to rewrite it to your needs.